# How to access a Django database from another python script?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django project, and I need to access the information inside that database(model).
This is my directory hierarchy-

[image]

I've seen a lot of questions on this subject, but everything I tried didn't work.
For example-

```
import models
# gives me this error-

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting 
INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either
define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

If I try to do this I get another error:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "OrAvivi.OrAvivi.settings")
import models
# gives me this error:
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

and it just continues...

I'm quite a newbie, spent most of my day on this so I would appreciate some help!

Comment: there is no such term as `django database` django uses any database,

i assume in your case `sqlite3` database, 

all data stored in this `database` and you can create sql query in it without django

Comment: oh ok, can you recommend a way to create that SQL query inside the python script itself?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the BEST way EVER!
import these modules-

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
```

Then, see what tables you have in your db and see the name of the table you want (you can do it here - [enter link description here](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/)

And then just do this to see the information you have!

```
def create_connection():
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn


def select_all_tasks(conn):
    """
    Query all rows in the tasks table
    :param conn: the Connection object
    :return:
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM to_excel_groups")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

This is how it looks in main():

```
DB_PATH = r'C:\Users\karin\PycharmProjects\Fiverr\OrAvivi\db.sqlite3'
conn = create_connection()
select_all_tasks(conn)
```